# Serving two directories for one virtual host

Tags: apache

Given the following:

```
/var/www -> web application 
/assets -> directory full of various assets
```

I cannot symlink /assets into /var/www, but need to include it as such:

```
www.foo.com -> web application
www.foo.com/assets -> should point to /assets
```

Is there a way to configure Apache to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the Alias directive, added to the host, which takes the URI and then the file location:

```
Alias /assets "/dir/foo/assets"
```